# AS3 Class Error gotoAndPlay(33)

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air

i´m trying to add admob ane to my game but i´m getting an error.

My error is this, when i import the class i got and erro in my project with the gotoAndPlay(33);

how can i define into class this gotoAndPlay(33); to stops error.

i´m using this package

```
  package
    {
import flash.display.Sprite;

import so.cuo.platform.admob.Admob;
import so.cuo.platform.admob.AdmobPosition;

public class SimpleDemo extends Sprite
{
    public function SimpleDemo()
    {
        super();
        var admob:Admob= Admob.getInstance();
        if(admob.supportDevice){
            admob.setKeys("your banner id ");
            admob.showBanner(Admob.BANNER,AdmobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        }
    }
}
}
```

So, i don´t know how to declare this gotoAndPlay(33) event in the class.

Since now thanks to all!

Comment: I say contact with admob developer and report the bug to him, this isn't your fault, if this code throws an error.

Comment: No, you don´t understand, in my project i set many gotoAndPlay. but when i insert this class i got an error with the gotoAndPlay functions. How can i declare it in the class itself?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like somewhere your code is trying to use `SimpleDemo` like it's a movie clip.

To give `SimpleDemo` all the powers of a `MovieClip`, make it extends that class

```
public class SimpleDemo extends MovieClip
```

instead of extending `Sprite` which doesn't have timeline functionality.

Now `SimpleDemo` will have all the MovieClip Methods, like `gotoAndPlay`.

If `SimpleDemo` is set as the class file for your document class (or a library object that has more than one frame or code on a frame), then you MUST extend MovieClip (though for the document class it CAN extend Sprite or DisplayObjectContainer if no timeline code or additional frames are used).

Comment: I solve the problem removing the class. I use now this same code in my timeline but without a package. Thanks to all